# Constructing a metric topology that is the same as the standard topology

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

Any help on this problem would be greatly appreciated. thanks!

$\textbf{Definition:}$ Let $\tau$ be the collection of subsets of $\mathbb{R}^n$ with the following property: $\forall x \in U,\; \exists\varepsilon \gt 0$ such that $B(x,\varepsilon)\subseteq U$, where $B(x,\varepsilon)$ is an open ball centered at $x$ with radius $\varepsilon$. Then $\tau$ is a topology called the standard topology on $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Construct a metric on $\mathbb{R}^n$ such that the resulting metric topology is the same as the standard topology on $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Comment: If you haven't already got a metric on $\mathbb R^n$ then what does $B(x,\epsilon)$ mean?

Comment: $B(x,\epsilon)$ is an open ball centered at x with radius $\epsilon$

Comment: OK... Tell me then, what does 'open ball centred at $x$ with radius $\epsilon$ mean'?

Comment: You can construct a metric space by defining defferent metric $d$ on $R^n$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your original question "Construct a metric such that the resulting metric topology is the same as the standard topology" makes no sense since, as Donkey_2009 was trying to tell you, you have to have a metric to begin with in order to define "radius" and "ball".  I suspect your problem was to construct **another** metric which gives the same topology.  That's easy- just define this new metric, d', as a positive multiple of the old metric, d: d'(x,y)= a d(x,y) where  a> 0.  In fact, it can be shown that two different metrics, on the same set, produce the same topology if and only if, given a ball in one metric, there exist a ball in the other metric completely contained in it.